# Symfony 3.3 Built-In server issue (PHP 7.1.9)

Tags: php, symfony, wamp, symfony-3.3

I'm just beginning with Symfony 3 but I'm stuck with a built-in server issue.

I am using wamp64 v3.0.6 with PHP 7.1.9 (and PHPStorm as IDE) on Windows 7.

I ran the built-in server once and got a response from localhost:8000 correctly but then, just like [this issue][1], I get the following error message when I try to access localhost:8000 on subsequent tries :

```
Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required'C:\wamp64\www\projectname\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\WebServerBundle/Resources/router.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in Unknown on line 0
```

I've tried uninstalling symfony, wamp64 and PHPstorm to try to identify the problem.

After reinstalling wamp (without running the server) and symfony I've noticed the following :

When I run the built-in server for the first time and immediately access localhost:8000, it works fine. But then the server stops without my pressing CTRL-C. When I restart the server and try to access localhost:8000 I now get said error message.

I've tried creating a another project using PHP 7.0.23 with the same results : once the server crashes, I can no longer load my project.

I'm hoping someone can provide an answer as regarding this issue. I've spent the past few hours searching the web for an answer and have found none.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can You Try to clear the cache folder ??

Comment: What does `php bin/symfony_requirements` give you? Also make sure the path to PHP is set correct in your Windows PATH environment variable. The PHP executable will be in your wamp folder.

Comment: @RishiKesh : which cach are you talking about. There are several caches out there...

Comment: disable your antivirus, download a new symfony project and things should work fine, for some reason on windows antivirus deletes/blocks/quarantine the router.php file so the first time it will work fine but then antivirus will go crazy and break your project. this is what fixed the issue at my end

Comment: It would appear that you are indeed right Baig, the problem appears to lie with the antivirus. Rather than disabling it alltogether, I have excluded the wamp directory (which is also where all symfony files and projects are stored) from my antiviral protection and the uilt-in server now appears stable. I'll just keep this topic open for a while until I have confirmed for a slightly longer period that there are no more issues. Thx for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit goes to Baig for this answer :

The source of the issue lies with the antivirus. To solve this, I've excluded the wamp directory (where symfony and my projects are also stored) from my antivirus and, voila, no more server crashes, everything works fine.